# Shell script to identify nodes is available

Tags: linux

Linux shell script to identify the node is active or down.

guptime

server1: 17:30:09 up  1:48,  2 users,  load average: 0.20, 0.19, 0.28
server2: 17:30:10 up  1:49,  0 users,  load average: 0.09, 0.11, 0.11
server3: 17:30:13 up  1:49,  0 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.13, 0.12
Server4:

Answer (score 0):

```
uptime IPfilename

#!/bin/bash
Command=$(basename $0)
if [ "$1" ]
then
  File=$1
else
  echo -n "File name: "
  read File
fi

for Server in $(cat $File)
do
  echo -n "$Server:"
  Output=$(ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 -o ConnectTimeout=4 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIKeyExchange=no -q $Server 'uptime' 2>/dev/null)
  echo "$Output"
done
```